# printf the value of %n in the same call - senseless?

Tags: c++, c

I can't find out the intention of the following part of `printf` specification at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

> There is a sequence point after the action of each conversion
>   specifier; this permits storing multiple %n results in the same
>   variable and **printing the value stored by %n earlier within the same
>   call.**

This reads as if the result of one (or even several) `%n` conversion specifier(s) could be printed out in the same `printf`-statement. 
But I can't find out how this could ever be achieved, because all arguments passed to a call of `printf` are evaluated before `printf`'s body is entered (there is a sequence point after argument evaluation). Hence, the value of a variable to which a `%n` would write is evaluated before `printf` has the chance to overwrite this variable's value with the "number of characters written so far":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int n = 0;
    printf("Hello, world!%n (%d first n); %n (%d second n)", &n ,n, &n, n);
    // will print out "Hello, world! (0 first n);  (0 second n)"

    return 0;
}
```

My question: If there isn't any chance of "printing the value stored by %n earlier within the same call", isn't then the respective part of the `printf` specification senseless or misleading?

What is the actual sense of the [c99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) statement:

> 7.19.6 Formatted input/output functions
>   (1) The formatted input/output functions shall behave as if there is a sequence point after the
>   actions associated with each specifier.

Is it to reduce the "chances" of getting undefined behaviour?

The question is tagged with c++ and c, because I think that this topic applies the same way to both languages.

Comment: C11 ref is `7.21.6  1`.

Comment: cppreference is now less senseless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does indeed only print zeros for the reasons you have identified correctly.

The statement in the Standard is still necessary because of blanket wording elsewhere that the behaviour of the program is undefined if an object is written to more than once without intervening sequence point. In effect, the statement is necessary to say that your code does not have undefined behaviour (unlike, say, `i = i++;`).

Comment: That's true of the part that says there's a sequence point. But what's the point of the part he highlighted in bold? That's not really possible, is it?

Comment: @Barmar: Well, of course you can't *read* the earlier writes, but the parts on bold are the only important consequence of the sequence point! If you only wrote to distinct output locations, you wouldn't need the sequence point.

Comment: @Kerrek Does this imply that printf() cannot be written as a normal, user-defined function?

Comment: @NeilButterworth No, it doesn't. There's a sequence point between statements, so all it requires is that storing to each `%n` be done in different statements.

Comment: @NeilButterworth And that the implementation of `printf()` process them from left to right.

Comment: @Barmar: I think if you squint at it the right way, you could argue that it's not actually specified *in which order* the specifiers are acted out. If the function keeps internal buffers, it could conceivably action them in any arbitrary order. So the final value of `n` could be *one of* the possible values, not necessarily the last one. I'm not sure if that's actually true or if there's additional wording forbidding that.

Answer (score 8):

This might be crazy, but I think the following is legal:

```
char s[2];
s[1] = '\0';
printf("Hi, world!%hhn%s", s, s);
```

`%hhn` takes a pointer to char. It writes `10` (the number of characters written so far) to `s[0]`. It then prints the string `s`, which is equivalent to `"\n"` or `(char[]){ 10, 0 }` (assuming ASCII).

Comment: I don't know what we would have done if the C standard didn't make this legal. :)

Comment: It's crazy, but also plausible.

Comment: Creative approach :-) One small issue would be that `hh` is supported for C++, but not for C. And it still let's me assume that printing a `%n` value in the narrower sense (i.e. as a number and not as an ASCII character) is not possible and that the bold part of cppreference.com is therefore misleading or senseless, right? Anyway, +1 for creativity!

Comment: @StephanLechner `hh` is supported for C since at least 1999.

Comment: @melpomene: You are right, according to the standard. cppreference.com has a note "(c++11)" on the `hh` (but not on the `h`). So I assumed it was supported since c11...

Answer (score 2):

One could imagine a compiler translating a call to `printf` into a sequence of individual calls to `fputs()` with string fragments computed by calls to conversion handlers.  This implementation might store the values into `n` before the value of `n` gets printed.  Would this be non conforming?

Modern compilers already perform small optimisations on `printf()`, such as converting `printf("Hello world\n");` into `puts("Hello world");` and `printf("\n");` into `fputchar('\n');`.  They also check format string and argument consistency... Further optimisations would lead to the above.

Comment: "*Would this be non conforming?*" - Yes. Compilation has to preserve semantics.

Comment: I suppose it would be non conforming, because - even for library functions like printf - arguments are evaluated before the funcion's code is entered. And optimizations must not change this semantics, right?